# Perform a text search in mongoDB and find reference document for each item in the collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am looking to build a way to search through a collection of trips. The search looks at whether the trip contains the passed city names (from and to location). Each trip model has the id of the user who created the entry. The query may return 0 or 100 items in the collection. I need to display data about the user in the search results. What is the best way for me to search the trip information and also get the user information.

Each trip in the results may have a different user.

I have thought about embedding the user information in the trip model but then I have to have a strategy for updating the information every time the user information changes. The trip to user(creator) relationship will always be one-to-one. Currently I am only embedding the user ID. This works fine for when I query one trip at a time, but not for a search.

Current Query: Looking for a match in the text

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var search = req.query;
    var query = {};

    if(search.origin) {
        query.origin = {
            $regex: search.origin,
            $options: 'i',
        };
    }

    if(search.destination) {
        query.destination = {
            $regex: search.destination,
            $options: 'i',
        };
    }

    Trip.find(query, function(err, trips) {
        if(err) return res.json( err );

        return res.json(trips);            
    });
});
```

Trip Model:

```
var TripSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    origin: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    destination: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    departing: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    returning: {
        type: Date
    },
});
```

User Model:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    }

});
```

Comment: What have you already came up with?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I updated my question. Currently I am performing a check to see if the provided origin and destination are in any existing documents. I haven't figured out how to efficiently go through the return trip array and get the user information as well.

Comment: hmm could you show your schema? It is a bit ambiguous now.

Comment: Hi @profesor79 I updated the question with an example of the models

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I did this right, but I ended up doing something like this. First I get the trips from my db based on the search string. The search is based on an origin and destination for a travel trip. Once I have the list of trips I iterate through the array and get the ID of each user and push it into another array. I take that array and I use the `db.model.find()` method with the `$in` operator to find the users from the array.

Because I need each trip to have a user object I iterate one more time through the trips, and assign the user obj to the trip.

I had to do some conversions to JSON because of the type of object mongoose returns. I can't just assign a new property. I converted it to JSON using the `toJSON()` method.

If someone knows a better approach or have any ideas how to improve the code bellow, any constructive feedback is welcomed.

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    if(!req.query.origin || !req.query.destination){
        return res.json({trips: []});
    }

    var search = req.query;
    var query = {};

    if(search.origin) {
        query.origin = {
            $regex: search.origin,
            $options: 'i',
        };
    }

    if(search.destination) {
        query.destination = {
            $regex: search.destination,
            $options: 'i',
        };
    }

    Trip.find(query, function(err, trips) {
        if(err) return res.json(err);

        var userIds = [];

        //get user ids from trip
        trips.forEach(function(trip) {
            userIds.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(trip.user));
        });

        var user = User.find({
            '_id': { $in: userIds}
        });

        user.select('id name');
        user.exec(function (err, users) {
            if (err) return res.json(err);

            var jsonTrips = [];
            var currentTrip;

            trips.forEach(function(trip) {
                currentTrip = trip.toJSON();
                currentTrip.user = findTripUser(trip.user, users);
                jsonTrips.push(currentTrip);
            });

            return res.json(jsonTrips);  
        });   
    });
});

function findTripUser(tripId, users) {
    var user;
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(JSON.stringify(users[i]._id)=== JSON.stringify(tripId)) {
            user = users[i];
            break;
        } 
    }

    return user.toJSON();
}
```